# Extract data from serialized array and output into PHP

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have this:

```
            case 'Bulk Discount':
            $postMeta = get_post_meta($product->ID, 'o-discount');
            echo $postMeta[0];
            break;
```

Where 'o-discount' is a post_meta which returns:

```
'a:4:{s:6:"enable";s:1:"1";s:4:"type";s:10:"percentage";s:10:"rules-type";s:9:"intervals";s:5:"rules";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:3:"min";s:1:"3";s:3:"max";s:0:"";s:8:"discount";s:1:"5";}}}'
```

I would like to echo data out of the serialized array so I can display it.

UPDATE:

I have tried to use unserialize with my array above but it does not returns any results. When I use the example I found below, it returns the "Manufactured in" - "Canada" result.

```
$mydata = 'a:5:{s:9:"engine_id";a:1:
{i:0;s:9:"300000225";}s:15:"transmission_id";a:1:
{i:0;s:6:"257691";}s:5:"plant";a:1:{i:0;s:23:"Oshawa, Ontario, 
Canada";}s:15:"Manufactured in";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"CANADA";}s:22:"Production 
Seq. Number";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"151411";}}';
$mydata = unserialize($mydata);
echo $mydata['Manufactured in'][0];
```

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Please see my update above in original post.

Comment: You are missing closing curly bracket at the end of $mydata string definition.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I see what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, actually your string is fine but you need to remove new line breaks from it (it should be one line)

Comment: It is one line. The first example before the update is one line.

Comment: unserialize() works fine on that string: https://3v4l.org/BuQG0

Comment: That works for me by printing it. How would I go about to echo certain values from the array?

Comment: @minemind The same way you would for any array. I assume you want the discount value, so `echo $unserialized['rules'][0]['discount'];`

Comment: @rickdenhaan - still learning here but that only appears to echo out an 'a' and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were just trying to access the wrong array key(s)...

```
$mydata = 'a:4:{s:6:"enable";s:1:"1";s:4:"type";s:10:"percentage";s:10:"rules-type";s:9:"intervals";s:5:"rules";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:3:"min";s:1:"3";s:3:"max";s:0:"";s:8:"discount";s:1:"5";}}}';

$mydata = unserialize($mydata);

print_r($mydata); // See the structure

echo $mydata['rules'][0]['discount']; // 5
```

Result: https://eval.in/853921

Comment: That is working, thank you. The other issue I have is getting that serialized array from the post ID so it's specific to each item. When I use '$postMeta = get_post_meta($product->ID, 'o-discount');' it does not return anything.